# Measure small mass change on heavy item

Tags: mass, measurements, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

I need to measure the change in mass on a large number of components we are developing with a size of a large orange and weighing between 0.3 and 1 kg to an accuracy of sub 10x10-6 kg.  The mass will change as part of production and will be needed as a quality control measure.  Most analytical balances I can find can only measure to this sort of accuracy for items of 200-300g.  I am only interested in the change in mass.

Has anyone any ideas how this be achieved on a small budget (USD 1000).

Comment: If you're doing part-per-million mass comparisons, you probably need to get into the metrology literature. See for instance [this web page](https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/kilogram/kilogram-disseminating-new-kilogram) or [this related technical article](https://www.nist.gov/publications/new-kilogram-definition-and-its-implications-high-precision-mass-tolerance-classes) to start mining references.

Comment: If you go up to a bit over $10,000 then it is a standard catalog item. Measuring one part in a million for a thousand dollars is just not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for your support and prompt feedback.  Unfortunately USD 10k will blow our ZAR budget out of the water.  I have looked at the workings of modern analytical scales and understand the limitations of current magnetic field designs wrt measuring relatively large masses to 5 decimal point accuracy,  I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the direction of an older/alternative measurement techniques.  However, I fear we have a long learning curve ahead of us - especially since our component is liquid filled.